# I have a .osm file, don't know what to do next?

Tags: mapping, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I created an indoor map file in JOSM, with different levels and tags for each room etc. Now I have it as a .osm file. How do I make it operational. Like how do I deploy it so that it can be used for indoor navigation. I also need some other features like calculating path from one place t other and search index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way by converting the given .osm file of my indoor map to GeoJSON using OSM2GEOJSON and then displaying that in awesome leaflet library. It's optimized for phones too. Displaying the map in leaflet was a sort of a hefty task but there are lot of plugins and forum answers that helped me. Reading geojson using ajax in leaflet and creating seperate layers for each floors,filtering those geojson layers based on there features.properties.level and then adding leaflet easy-buttons to display each layer. There are also other plugins which can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically searching for an offline routing and map drawing solution. This has already been answered multiple times. You could even use a full-featured offline solution such as OsmAnd if you convert your map into a suitable format with the OsmAndMapCreator.